# Big commerce Pay in store option

Tags: bigcommerce

I created a dummy store using Big Commerce.

It has a Pay In store option, i just wanted to know whether i can let users to check for stores first after choosing the Pay in Store option on the Check Out page and then click the checkout button? I could not find any way to achieve this.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for us to help you, we need to see actual code or maybe some of your architecture. It's really hard for us to debug a verbal description of your code. Have a read through this to give you an idea of the kind of information we need form you in order to help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There isn't out of the box functionality in Bigcommerce that allows a customer to choose what store they are going to pay at. You can use an app like [Store Finder](https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/store-finder/) so your customers could find the store locations closest to them. You can do a workaround like creating shipping zones based on zip codes that are assigned to specific stores or ask customers to specify the pickup store in the order notes.